# Rails's content_tag analog in jQuery or Backbone?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, underscore.js

Are there anything similar in jQuery or Backbone to [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)
 helper method from Rails?

I want to built a complex piece of html which I want to generate in run time on client side. So I'm looking for elegant approach to do this. (e.g. it's definitely not string concatenation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can do:

```
$('<p />' {text: 'Hello world'});
$('<div />', {text: 'Hello world!', class: 'strong'});
```

If you want something slightly more complex:

```
var $container = $('<div />', {class: 'strong'});
$('<p />', {text: 'Hello world'}).appendTo($container);
```